# How to set a custom request header using a HTTP Interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to add a custom request header for requests that go through the retry mechanism. I have an interceptor that currently filters any requests that specifically timeout while also logging the error details.

What I'm unsure of is, where do I set the header during the retry. I know the `req.clone` I currently have is incorrect but I having trouble figuring out how to access both the req and the error at the same time.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
return next.handle(req).pipe(
    timeout(30000),
    retryWhen((err) =>
        err.pipe(
            filter((error) => !(error instanceof ProgressEvent)),
            tap((error) => {
                // We'll keep track of the number of retries

                if (count > RETRY_COUNT) {
                    // abort retry
                } else {
                    // retry and set a custom header specifically to each of the retried requests

                    // This doesn't work since we are not changing the source observable and I don't think we even have access to the original req here.
                    const newReq = req.clone({
                        headers: req.headers.set('X-Retry-Count', count.toString())
                    })
                }
            }),
            delay(2000)
        )
    ),
    catchError((error) => {
        // Log the error...
    })
);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using `defer` to create the original observable. `defer` allows you to define an observable factory that will get called with each subscription. This way you can create a different one for the first request and each of the retries.

so you could do something like this:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  let retryCount = 0;

  // helper function to generate the request based on the current retryCount 
  function generateRequest() {
    return retryCount === 0
      ? req
      : req.clone({
          headers: req.headers.set('X-Retry-Count', retryCount.toString()),
        });
  }


  return defer(() => next.handle(generateRequest())).pipe(
    timeout(30000),
    retry({
      delay: (error) => {
        if (error instanceof ProgressEvent || retryCount >= MAX_RETRIES) {
          return throwError(() => error);
        }

        retryCount++;
        return timer(2000);
      },
    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      // Log the error...
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go and will update here.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this instruction after creating newReq:

```
const newReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('X-Retry-Count', count.toString()) })
next.handle(newReq).subscribe({ complete: () => count ++ }); // retry running and count incrementation
```